# How are circular dependencies dealt with inside MBSE?

Tags: dynamics, modeling, simulation, systems-engineering, simulink

How are circular dependencies (best) managed inside of MBSE environments? Let's say I have two properties that are linked to each other / they are linked to properties that affect each other.

How is this managed both from an abstract "best-practices" point of view?

How does MBSE/simulation software deal with this?